# How can I make 'uName' display the correct name that the user inputs after clarifying checks?

Tags: python

I am very new to Python, as you can probably tell from the code. To begin, I am trying to have the user input their name and store that in a global variable that I can access all throughout my code...preferably named `uName`.

What's happening is during the loop cycle, it asks the user 'Is this your name?' after they input the first response. If I hit type anything but 'yes' or 'Yes', it will re-ask them to input the name. BUT, when they finally hit 'Yes', the program prints the very first name they entered.

Also, any tips on code structure or wording is helpful...

**game.py**

```
from decisions import *
import decisions

global globalname
globalname = ''

def gameEngine(uName):

    looper = 0

    while looper == 0:

        print ('You said your name is,  ') + uName + ('...')
        clarifier = raw_input('Is that correct?\n')

        if clarifier == 'yes' or clarifier == 'Yes':    
            namePrinter(answer) 
        else:       
            decisions.userDecisions(username)       

def namePrinter(uName):
    print uName 

gameEngine(answer)
```

**decisions.py**

```
username = ''

def userDecisions(inputs):
    response = raw_input("Please enter your name...\n>>> ")
    return response

answer = userDecisions(username)
```

Answer (score 1):

The specific issue that you are encountering is that you are first running the contents of decisions.py though the import statement in game.py. Through that, you have set the variable "answer" to be equal to the first name that the user inputs.

Then you are calling the gameEngine function in game.py, supplying the "answer" variable from decisions.py as the argument, which is stored in "uName". Upon the user entering another name the name is not stored anywhere and is thrown out with the following line.

```
decisions.userDecisions(username)
```

You can assign the return of that statement to a variable such as "uName", and that will get you closer to what you want to do.

```
uName = decisions.userDecisions(username)
```

The next issue is that when you are printing out the name, you are printing out the variable "answer" as opposed to "uName". This is what is mainly causing the issue of the first name always being printed out.

```
namePrinter(answer)
```

This could be resolved by passing in the "uName" variable instead.

```
namePrinter(uName)
```

Also if you want the final chosen name to be stored in the global variable you can assign the final user chosen name to the gloabl variable after the user confirms that the nameis correct.

```
globalname = uName
```

However, you may want to be careful about a few parts of the structure of your code.

First, you may want to try not to use global variables. Instead you should be passing around the name though the functions which use it. If you have other player information that you need to access often, you can create a Player class and object to store that information in a single object which can be passed around into functions as needed.

Second, as the userDecisions function does not use its arguement "inputs", you can remove that arguement, as it isn't used.

Third, you may want to be careful about running code through import statements alone. Generally when you are importing a source file, you should be importing the functions, and not rely upon imports to directly run code. For example you can remove the non-function lines of decisions.py and simply run the following in game.py instead.

```
gameEngine(decisions.userDecisions())
```

I reccomend that you look up some resources on functions and passing arguement in Python, as they might be able to explain the underlying concepts a bit better.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. This is by no means an attempt at anything other than learning the relationship between functions inside of different files, which is why I wanted to separate the code into two files. I also had no idea that simply typing 'import thisfile' would automatically run the contents of that file...that is also helpful info. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have screwed up with the variables and their scope. Read more about them [here](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Variables_and_Scope.html).

To give you a perspective regarding the *scope of variables* concisely, look at this code snippet:

```
# This is a global variable
a = 0

if a == 0:
    # This is still a global variable
    b = 1

def my_function(c):
    # this is a local variable
    d = 3
    print(c)
    print(d)

# Now we call the function, passing the value 7 as the first and only parameter
my_function(7)

# a and b still exist
print(a)
print(b)

# c and d don't exist anymore -- these statements will give us name errors!
print(c)
print(d)
```

---

Regarding your code, you may want to have a look at these issues:

1. The `answer` variable is not accessible in the **game.py** module.
2. So is the case with `username` variable in the `decisions.userDecisions(username)` call.
3. The `decisions.userDecisions(username)` call in the `gameEngine(uName)` method is not storing the response to any variable and hence the response will be lost.
4. You are declaring global variable `globalname` but not assigning any value to it (of course other than `''`).

---

P.S.: I was tempted to do your homework for you, but then probably this is good enough information for you to learn more. ;)